# How to retain windows 10 display settings on different desk setups

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have tried to google this but not having much luck.

I'm hoping this is a simple fix.

I have a corporate windows 10 surface device that I use at home and in the office, and both setups are different, at home I have 2x 24 inch screens and in the office I have 1 massive 35" monitor and everytime I change locations I have to keep changing my display/screen settings and reconfiguring my screen layout.

Is there a way for retain these settings on the system once configured, so I can avoid having to constantly change screen / display settings when ever I work in the office or at home?

Ideally I just want to plug in the device and it automatically detects the layout.

Hope this made sense :)

Thanks

Comment: Try different Windows User Profiles - one for home and one for office. Then try setting up the monitors for each profile. See if that works. You can set up and test a separate profile quite easily.

Comment: Hi John, unfortunately this not possible with my corporate device.