# How to make Windows 11 use same multimonitor setup at work and home?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have a company-issued laptop that I use both at work and home. I used to have different multimonitor setups at each location, but now I finally have the same 3-monitor setup (two external displays and the built-in display), physically set up in the same relative positions, albeit with different brands of monitors connected to (I think) the same model of docking station.

Unfortunately, even though both setups have the same-numbered screens (1, 2, and 3 are in the same positions both at work and at home), sometimes the layout changes to one of the previous (no longer correct) 3-monitor configurations when I disconnect from one location and reconnect at the other, and I have to manually reconfigure all over again (and move windows over that I left open in sleep mode).

How do I make the computer remember the setup so that when I plug the machine in at home, everything is exactly where I left it at work, and vice versa?

Note that this question is similar to [another one](https://superuser.com/q/1753010/1760933)  I found while researching, with the differences being (1) I want to preserve the *same* configuration at two locations with physically compatible monitor layouts; rather than remember two incompatible configurations, one for each location; and (2) I am using Windows 11 instead of Windows 10.

Comment: FYI: In this regard there are no differences between Windows 10 and Windows 11 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It should already work as you described it, but it sounds like it keeps messing up your screen drivers(or screen IDs).

In your place i would go to Device manager and remove all my Monitors(while screens are unplugged, use View>Show hidden devices), would only skip "integrated" one. Reset laptop, and plug screens back on both locations.

Comment: Sounds like a good thing to try, but I think that needs admin access, which I don't have.

Comment: @JohnY - So have your System Administrator perform the fix action.